# How to express List of Type in immutable?

Tags: immutable.js

Is there any way how to express List of type in immutable js?

Something like:

```
const InitialState = Record({
    propertiesTotals: List.of(Record({
        propertyId: null,
        value: 0,
    })),
});
```

The List.of is acctutal [method](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/of) in immutablejs but it does not do the thing.

Comment: What for? Defining `PropTypes` in react?

Comment: for defining how should state look like in redux, and be able to easily read the structure of data.

Comment: Would be great to have this feature. However, given that Immutable structures decouple data type from the structure itself, I doubt if this would ever happen. For now I have resorted to having type/schema validation in a wrapper over my underlying immutable state.

Comment: Cam across [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-immutable) just now... It has complex type List support, which fits your use case, have a look.